# How to make integrated terminal tabs show host name?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On my machine (with new install of vscode), it shows integrated terminal title when invoking WSL-Ubuntu to be <user>@<host>:<pwd>.

Once terminal is open, its title never changes. When I ssh to a remote host as user 'oracle', title does not change. But, when I 'sudo su - ' on the same remote host, title changes to to 'root@<remote_host>'.

I did not understand this behavior and where/how it is configured? Is there a way to have terminal title reflect <user>@ when I ssh to remote hosts? In otherwords, I want title to reflect the host I'm connected to. When there are 15 terminal tabs opens, it does help to be able to tell them apart by hostname at least.

If there is no direct way, any clever workarounds?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218174/how-to-show-the-host-name-in-linux-commandline-prompt

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of the PS1 variable settings. I do not think this answer relates to my question, however.